# Shell script - I want to traverse through 2nd argument to last argument

Tags: shell, arguments

How can I traverse through 2nd argument to last argument
like:

```
for arg in $2-$@
do
  echo $i
done
```

Please help

Comment: Here is a very good book on bash scripting: http://linux.die.net/abs-guide/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, don't trust the arguments... they may contain spaces, or other special meta characters to the shell. Double quotes are your friends in shell scripts.

```
shift;           #eat $1
for arg in "$@"
do
  echo "$arg"
done
```

When put in double quotes the "$@" takes on special magic to assure words are retained. Much better then $*.  "$*" would process all arguments at once.

Double quotes are not a perfect solution, just the best easy one.

Answer (score 2):

Use `shift` in `bash`.

```
shift
for arg in $@
do
  echo $arg
done
```

Answer (score 0):

```
args=("$@")

for arg in $(seq 2 `expr $# - 1`)
do
  echo ${args[$arg]}
done
```